# The Android Studio keep telling me that cannot find the file

Tags: java, android, ioexception

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    Button mBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_Quit_button);
    mBtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("clicks", "You Clicked B1");
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    StartActivity.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    Button mBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_Next_button);
    mBtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("clicks", "You Clicked B2");
            TextView username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_text);

            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/ExperimentLog");
            if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdir();
            }

            Username = username.getText().toString();


            save(root, Username);

            Intent i = new Intent(
                    StartActivity.this,
                    Test1_0.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

public void save(File dir, String string) {
    try {
        File filepath = new File(dir, Username + ".txt");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filepath);
        writer.append(string);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

This is the code I have. As you can see that i want the second button to go to the next activity and save the text I get from the editText start_Next_button. And a save method to write the string into the file created. 
But the when I press the button on the AVD, android studio shows this:

```
04-28 10:09:44.242 2379-2379/com.android.mick.encodingaidingexperiment W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/ExperimentLog/Name.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-28 10:09:44.242 2379-2379/com.android.mick.encodingaidingexperiment W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
04-28 10:09:44.242 2379-2379/com.android.mick.encodingaidingexperiment W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
04-28 10:09:44.242 2379-2379/com.android.mick.encodingaidingexperiment W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
04-28 10:09:44.242 2379-2379/com.android.mick.encodingaidingexperiment W/System.err:     at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:42)
04-28 10:09:44.242 2379-2379/com.android.mick.encodingaidingexperiment W/System.err:     at com.android.mick.encodingaidingexperiment.StartActivity.save(StartActivity.java:74)
04-28 10:09:44.242 2379-2379/com.android.mick.encodingaidingexperiment W/System.err:     at com.android.mick.encodingaidingexperiment.StartActivity$2.onClick(StartActivity.java:61)
04-28 10:09:44.242 2379-2379/com.android.mick.encodingaidingexperiment W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
04-28 10:09:44.242 2379-2379/com.android.mick.encodingaidingexperiment W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
04-28 10:09:44.242 2379-2379/com.android.mick.encodingaidingexperiment W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-28 10:09:44.242 2379-2379/com.android.mick.encodingaidingexperiment W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-28 10:09:44.242 2379-2379/com.android.mick.encodingaidingexperiment W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
04-28 10:09:44.242 2379-2379/com.android.mick.encodingaidingexperiment W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
04-28 10:09:44.242 2379-2379/com.android.mick.encodingaidingexperiment W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-28 10:09:44.242 2379-2379/com.android.mick.encodingaidingexperiment W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
04-28 10:09:44.242 2379-2379/com.android.mick.encodingaidingexperiment W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-28 10:09:44.242 2379-2379/com.android.mick.encodingaidingexperiment W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-28 10:09:44.242 2379-2379/com.android.mick.encodingaidingexperiment W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
04-28 10:09:44.242 2379-2379/com.android.mick.encodingaidingexperiment W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
04-28 10:09:44.242 2379-2379/com.android.mick.encodingaidingexperiment W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
04-28 10:09:44.242 2379-2379/com.android.mick.encodingaidingexperiment W/System.err:    ... 14 more
```

BTW I use AVD galaxy Nexus running android 6.0

Comment: have you added `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission??

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         package="com.android.mick.encodingaidingexperiment">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Blatant speculation: `/sdcard/ExperimentLog` is a file instead of a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `/` after `ExperimentLog` and then `mkdir()` or `mkdirs()`.

Comment: Why would this help?  There's already a `mkdir()` call if it doesn't exist, and [there's no requirement that there be a slash at the end](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File#mkdir()).

Answer (score -1):

first of all the exception is about file is not exist, so you need create that folder and file if it doesn't exist on your directory.
you need a try catch block to handle FileNotFoundException.
and also you can use `Files.createFile(thePath);` to create file if not exist.

Comment: you need to catch throwed exceptions most of times, I hope this helps you

Comment: Check [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileWriter#FileWriter(java.io.File)): IOException is thrown if the file "does not exist **but cannot be created**" (emphasis added).

Answer (score -1):

Just try this

```
File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/ExperimentLog"+".txt");
```

instead of

```
File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/ExperimentLog");
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense: why would naming the *directory* "ExperimentLog.txt" help?